# QT on Windows - RunTime Error when MainWindow is closed

Tags: qt, mingw

I'm building a Qt UI Application and I upgraded my Qt version from 5.1.1 to 5.4.1 with mingw-49 compiler on my Windows Machine. When I try to close the MainWindow of my Application I get the following error:
`Runtime Error: This Application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.`
When this error happens the Application Output tabs shows the following message:
`ASSERT: "allWidgets" in file kernel\qwidget.cpp, line 1110
The Application is exited with an error code of 255.`
This error however is not happening with Qt version 5.1.1 with the same code. I tried installing Qt 5.4.1 in linux and it seems to run without any problem. So is this a Qt bug or is it problem with the mingw-49 version or is there something in my code that could cause the problem?

Comment: Please show the code that triggers the error. You can find it with a debugger.

Comment: No the run-time error I get is not from my code. When I click the close button of the main-window, I get this problem. And I've not overridden the closeEvent() slot of the MainWindow. Also this problem does not happen every-time and it happens only with Qt.5.4.1.